# Setting up Error message DataAnnotation in Unique constraint in code first approach in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I made this model class.Here I set `Email` property as a Unique key. When I try to insert existing `Email` it shows unique key error. Thats fine, but I want to set error message DataAnnotations in the model class.

Here is the code:

```
[String Length(450)]
[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond",1,IsUnique=true)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Error message for Index data annotation in EF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26306821/2907017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "key"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916642/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)